# How to configure Tika 0.9 with Solr 3.1

Tags: solr, apache-tika, solr-cell

can you give me the Steps to configure Tika 0.9 with Solr 3.1

```
<requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <!-- All the main content goes into "text"... if you need to return
           the extracted text or do highlighting, use a stored field. -->
      <str name="fmap.content">text</str>
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>

      <!-- capture link hrefs but ignore div attributes -->
      <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.a">links</str>
      <str name="fmap.div">ignored_</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

This one i use in solrconfig.xml to configure
Please help me on that

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Tika (and dependencies) installed in solr, that ought to be all you need to do.

Have you had a read through the [ExtractingRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) wiki page? It has quite a bit of information, and handily also has several recipes using curl to let you test that it's all working properly.

Comment: I am very new person in Tika and Solr so, how to install dependencies of Tika

Comment: Try using the solr example first, see the wiki page for details.

Comment: can you give me the step by step to configure